# How to group by bitmask?

Tags: mysql, bitmap, group-by

Tried to use query2 to replace query1, but it seems not work. Is there a way of making query1 simple? query1 will have lots of redundant statements when the WHERE clause is long.

Query1:

```
    SELECT "RUNNING", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 1 UNION
    SELECT "MISSING", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 2 UNION
    SELECT "ERROR", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 4 UNION
    SELECT "WARNING", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 8 UNION
    SELECT "FAILED", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 16 UNION
    SELECT "RESTARTING", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 32 UNION
    SELECT "OFF", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 64 UNION
    SELECT "LOW", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 128 UNION
    SELECT "RETIRED", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 256 UNION
    SELECT "UNKNOWN", COUNT(*) FROM devices WHERE status_id & 512;
```

Query2:

```
    SELECT (CASE 
     WHEN (status_id & 1) THEN "RUNNING" 
     WHEN (status_id & 2) THEN "MISSING" 
     WHEN (status_id & 4) THEN "ERROR" 
     WHEN (status_id & 8) THEN "WARNING" 
     WHEN (status_id & 16) THEN "FAILED" 
     WHEN (status_id & 32) THEN "RESTARTING" 
     WHEN (status_id & 64) THEN "OFF" 
     WHEN (status_id & 128) THEN "LOW" 
     WHEN (status_id & 256) THEN "RETIRED" 
     WHEN (status_id & 512) THEN "UNKNOWN" END
    ) AS DS, COUNT(*)
    FROM devices
    GROUP BY DS;
```